# Click Icon to Expand Image in Modal

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a project that requires the user to be able to click on a few photos to expand them in a modal view.  While we are using Bootstrap 4 for the page formatting, I have been told not to use the Bootstrap Modal framework because of issues with device compatibility. I also can't use plugins because of licensing concerns.  So, I found and emulated this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

This is my code (with dummy images):

```
<!-- Code for Modal -->
<div class="popupHolder" id="popup1">
    <div class="popupFlex">
        <div class="popup">
            <div class="popupClose">&times;</div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="popupCnt">
                        <img class="imgpopup" id="img01">
                        <br clear="all" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Container that holds gallery -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="imgGridBox">
        <img class="img-fluid myImg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/330px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt="img1">
        <img class="imgOpen" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6d/Windows_Settings_app_icon.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="imgGridBox">
        <img class="img-fluid myImg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c4/Micah_1.jpg/375px-Micah_1.jpg" alt="Img2">
        <img class="imgOpen" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6d/Windows_Settings_app_icon.png">
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imgGridBox {
  position: relative;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}

.imgGridBox img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.imgOpen {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 20px;
    max-height: 20px;
}

.popupHolder {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 100vw;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  z-index: 888888;
}

.popupFlex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.popup {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  max-width: 95%;
}

.popupClose {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.5rem;
  top: 0.5rem;
  color: #34B233;
  font-size: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999999;
}

.popupCnt {
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.popupCnt #img01 {
  width: 50vw;
}
```

Script:

```
var modal = document.getElementById("popup1");
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var open = document.getElementById("imgOpen");

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  var img = images[i];
  img.onclick = function (evt) {
    console.log(evt);
    modal.style.visibility = "visible";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
  };
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("popupClose")[0];
span.onclick = function () {
  modal.style.visibility = "hidden";
};

$(".popupHolder").click(function () {
  modal.style.visibility = "hidden";
});

$(".popupCnt").click(function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  modal.style.visibility = "hidden";
});
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/kaelahc/pen/yLeXwXm

It works great when clicking on the image itself but I'm not sure how to alter the JS to make the icon clickable (preferably instead of the image). Can anyone recommend a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through images and binding click on images in your code here :

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  var img = images[i];
  img.onclick = function (evt) {
    console.log(evt);
    modal.style.visibility = "visible";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
  };
}
```

What you need is to loop through gear icon, and then retrieve the image with whatever technique (I used parentNode and querySelector here)

It will look like that :

```
const opens = document.querySelectorAll(".imgOpen");

opens.forEach(open => {
  open.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    modal.style.visibility = 'visible';
    modalImg.src = open.parentNode.querySelector('.myImg').src;
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  This really helped.  Very simple and I wish I'd asked hours ago.

Comment: No problem. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a jQuery solution, try adding this event listener to all of the gear icons:

```js
$(".imgOpen").click(function (event) {
  modal.style.visibility = "visible";
  modalImg.src = $(event.target).siblings('.myImg').attr('src');
});
```

Comment: I'm not super familiar with jQuery... When I tried this out, it only worked on the first instance and subsequent clicks did nothing.  I'm sure I missed something but the other answer worked for me.  Thank you!

Comment: Hey no problem, thanks for the reply. I'm glad you got a working solution either way!